# Google Calendar API - No such module 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate the Google Calendar API on iOS. I've followed the [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift). I've managed to get the objective-c version to run but I need to get it to work in Swift. I'm getting an error loading the module 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'

I'm using cocoapods as shown in the example. All looks to be loaded fine on the pod side, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Has someone succeeded to run the google example in swift ?

THANKS!

Comment: Try not to use the pods for Google libraries. Check [this Github post](https://github.com/aytek/iOS-Swift-Google-Drive-Document-Picker/issues/2).

Answer (score 1):

Linking the library with the binary resolved the module not found error.

[image: link binary with library]

I then ran into another error "Value of type 'GTLRCalendarService' has no member 'authorizer'" in the signin method (Two instances of the error). Found a solution to this error [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#using-a-swift-bridging-header)

Solved this by creating a bridging header where I included these lines

```
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherService.h>
```

[Here's my Xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbtcm4ob4o25j6t/Calendar.zip?dl=0) incase it can help someone.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I have the same issue with authorizer.

Comment: @Seb Project not there in dropbox